# Scala trait override method with multiple parameters

Tags: scala, methods, parameters, pattern-matching, overriding

I would love to create trait called filter with method execute and force all children to have execute but in some filters execute may need some other parameters and some don't.
Is here any way how to create child with different parameters and parent ?

Maybe pattern matching could be solution in some way. Also Im new user of Scala so I ll be happy for all advices

Example code:

```
trait filter{
    def execute (photo: Photo): Photo 
}

object FooFilter{
    // Here we will get compile error due that execute method is not overloading anything
    override def execute (photo: Photo, foo: Foo): Photo = {...} 
}
```

Comment: First of all, the compilation error you're getting is b/c your `FooFilter` doesn't extend `filter`, that's why when you use the override modifier it shows the compilation error

Comment: Second, you can create a builder pattern in which a builder implements a trait `execute`, but before you execute, you can use another method like `addFilter` which will use generics to make sure the filter you're adding is related to the builder you're using. Just thinking out loud

Comment: _"how to create a child with different parameters and parent"_ you can't, think if you are using a value of type `Filter` but then it is actually a `FooFilter` under the hood, then when you call `execute` it would blow up. - Maybe explain what is the meta-problem you are trying to solve.